# Implementation of homography in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, homography

I am trying to implement a network in TensorFlow that learns to predict homography ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision))). My network will output a 4-dimensional vector, which will be used to translate 2 images horizontally and vertically. Then, I calculate the error with a ground truth using a central crop ([`tf.image.central_crop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/central_crop))of these warped images. I tried implementing it, and for the translation part, I used [`tf.contrib.image.translate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/translate). But, the gradients are not flowing to the variables of the network. How can I fix this problem? This is the error that I am getting:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'get_tr/w1:0' shape=(3, 3, 6, 64) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/b1:0' shape=(20, 298, 298, 64) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/w2:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 64) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/b2:0' shape=(20, 296, 296, 64) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/w3:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 128) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/b3:0' shape=(20, 147, 147, 128) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/w4:0' shape=(3, 3, 128, 128) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/b4:0' shape=(20, 73, 73, 128) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/w5:0' shape=(5, 5, 128, 128) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/fc1/kernel:0' shape=(609408, 512) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/fc1/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/fc2/kernel:0' shape=(512, 1024) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/fc2/bias:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/fc_o/kernel:0' shape=(1024, 4) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'get_tr/fc_o/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("mean_squared_error/value:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).
```

Here is the code for getting this transformation vector.

```
def get_transform_vectors(self):
    # Start of transformation prediction network

    image = tf.concat((self.img_train_1, self.img_train_2), 3)

    with tf.variable_scope('get_tr'):
        w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 6, 64], stddev=0.1),
                    name='w1')
        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(image,
                                    filter=w1,
                                    strides=(1,1,1,1),
                                    padding="VALID",
                                    name='conv1')

        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=tf.shape(conv1), stddev=0.1),
                    name='b1')
        conv1_ = tf.nn.relu(conv1+b1, name='conv1_')

        w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 64, 64], stddev=0.1),
                    name='w2')
        conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1_,
                                    filter=w2,
                                    strides=(1,1,1,1),
                                    padding="VALID",
                                    name='conv2')
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=tf.shape(conv2), stddev=0.1),
                    name='b2')
        conv2_ = tf.nn.relu(conv2+b2, name='conv2_')

        w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 64, 128], stddev=0.1),
                    name='w3')
        conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv2_,
                                    filter=w3,
                                    strides=(1,2,2,1),
                                    padding="VALID",
                                    name='conv3')
        b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=tf.shape(conv3), stddev=0.1),
                    name='b3')
        conv3_ = tf.nn.relu(conv3+b3, name='conv3_')

        w4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 128, 128], stddev=0.1),
                    name='w4')
        conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv3_,
                                    filter=w4,
                                    strides=(1,2,2,1),
                                    padding="VALID",
                                    name='conv4')

        b4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=tf.shape(conv4), stddev=0.1),
                    name='b4')
        conv4_ = tf.nn.relu(conv4+b4, name='conv4_')

        w5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[5, 5, 128, 128], stddev=0.1),
                    name='w5')
        conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv4_,
                                    filter=w5,
                                    strides=(1,1,1,1),
                                    padding="VALID",
                                    name='conv5')

        conv5_ = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv5)

        fc1 = tf.layers.dense(conv5_, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc1')
        fc2 = tf.layers.dense(fc1, 1024, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc2')
        fc_o = tf.layers.dense(fc2, 4, name='fc_o')

    return fc_o
```

This is the code for translating the image and calculating the loss.

```
self.img_o = tf.contrib.image.translate(self.img_train_1,
                                            tf.cast(tf.reshape(self.tr_vector[:, 0:2], [self.batch_size,2]),
                                                    dtype=tf.float32)) +\
                 tf.contrib.image.translate(self.img_train_2,
                                            tf.cast(tf.reshape(self.tr_vector[:, 2:4], [self.batch_size,2]),
                                                    dtype=tf.float32))

self.loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.img_o, self.img_label)
self.optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(self.loss)
```

Comment: The operations you mention appear to have defined gradients (at least in version 1.11.0).  Without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to tell what might be the issue.

Comment: @jdehesa I have added the code that might be have caused the error. Please look into it.

Comment: @jdehesa are you sure about gradients for `tf.contrib.image.translate` operation?

Comment: [`translate`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.11.0/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/image_ops.py#L101-L126) is based on [`transform`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.11.0/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/image_ops.py#L221-L304), which uses the op [`ImageProjectiveTransformV2`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.11.0/tensorflow/contrib/image/ops/image_ops.cc#L109-L118), which has the gradient, [`_image_projective_transform_grad`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.11.0/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/image_ops.py#L395-L424)

Comment: There are some other operations involved, but they are standard ops like concatenation and so on, so I _think_ it should backpropagate fine.

Comment: Ah, wait, I see what is the problem. The gradient is defined, but only for the image (that is, you could "optimize" the image). You are trying to train to find the right translations, though, but those gradients are not provided.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, I am trying to find the right translation vector. Is there a workaround by optimizing the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only interested in optimizing translations, I came up with this function to perform a translation and have gradients for the vectors, using [`@tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient):

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def my_img_translate(imgs, translates):
    # Interpolation model has to be fixed due to limitations of tf.custom_gradient
    interpolation = 'NEAREST'
    imgs_translated = tf.contrib.image.translate(imgs, translates, interpolation=interpolation)
    def grad(img_translated_grads):
        translates_x = translates[:, 0]
        translates_y = translates[:, 1]
        translates_zero = tf.zeros_like(translates_x)
        # X gradients
        imgs_x_grad = (imgs[:, :, :-2] - imgs[:, :, 2:]) / 2
        imgs_x_grad = tf.concat([(imgs[:, :, :1] - imgs[:, :, 1:2]),
                                 imgs_x_grad,
                                 (imgs[:, :, -2:-1] - imgs[:, :, -1:])], axis=2)
        imgs_x_grad_translated = tf.contrib.image.translate(
            imgs_x_grad, tf.stack([translates_x, translates_zero], axis=1),
            interpolation=interpolation)
        translates_x_grad = tf.reduce_sum(img_translated_grads * imgs_x_grad_translated, axis=(1, 2, 3))
        # Y gradients
        imgs_y_grad = (imgs[:, :-2] - imgs[:, 2:]) / 2
        imgs_y_grad = tf.concat([(imgs[:, :1] - imgs[:, 1:2]),
                                 imgs_y_grad,
                                 (imgs[:, -2:-1] - imgs[:, -1:])], axis=1)
        imgs_y_grad_translated = tf.contrib.image.translate(
            imgs_y_grad, tf.stack([translates_zero, translates_y], axis=1),
            interpolation=interpolation)
        translates_y_grad = tf.reduce_sum(img_translated_grads * imgs_y_grad_translated, axis=(1, 2, 3))
        # Complete gradient
        translates_grad = tf.stack([translates_x_grad, translates_y_grad], axis=1)
        return None, translates_grad
    return imgs_translated, grad
```

Note that in this case I am not returning any gradient for the images, since these will not be optimized (but if you wanted that, you could in principle use the builtin gradient for the translation operation).

I tested this for a simple use case of translating an image so its center had the highest value:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

@tf.custom_gradient
def my_img_translate(imgs, translates):
    # Interpolation model has to be fixed due to limitations of tf.custom_gradient
    interpolation = 'NEAREST'
    imgs_translated = tf.contrib.image.translate(imgs, translates, interpolation=interpolation)
    def grad(img_translated_grads):
        translates_x = translates[:, 0]
        translates_y = translates[:, 1]
        translates_zero = tf.zeros_like(translates_x)
        # X gradients
        imgs_x_grad = (imgs[:, :, :-2] - imgs[:, :, 2:]) / 2
        imgs_x_grad = tf.concat([(imgs[:, :, :1] - imgs[:, :, 1:2]),
                                 imgs_x_grad,
                                 (imgs[:, :, -2:-1] - imgs[:, :, -1:])], axis=2)
        imgs_x_grad_translated = tf.contrib.image.translate(
            imgs_x_grad, tf.stack([translates_x, translates_zero], axis=1),
            interpolation=interpolation)
        translates_x_grad = tf.reduce_sum(img_translated_grads * imgs_x_grad_translated, axis=(1, 2, 3))
        # Y gradients
        imgs_y_grad = (imgs[:, :-2] - imgs[:, 2:]) / 2
        imgs_y_grad = tf.concat([(imgs[:, :1] - imgs[:, 1:2]),
                                 imgs_y_grad,
                                 (imgs[:, -2:-1] - imgs[:, -1:])], axis=1)
        imgs_y_grad_translated = tf.contrib.image.translate(
            imgs_y_grad, tf.stack([translates_zero, translates_y], axis=1),
            interpolation=interpolation)
        translates_y_grad = tf.reduce_sum(img_translated_grads * imgs_y_grad_translated, axis=(1, 2, 3))
        # Complete gradient
        translates_grad = tf.stack([translates_x_grad, translates_y_grad], axis=1)
        return None, translates_grad
    return imgs_translated, grad

# Test operations
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, None])
translates = tf.Variable([0, 0], dtype=tf.float32)
translates_tiled = tf.tile(translates[tf.newaxis], (tf.shape(imgs)[0], 1))
imgs_translated = my_img_translate(imgs, translates_tiled)
imgs_midpoint = imgs_translated[:, tf.shape(imgs_translated)[1] // 2, tf.shape(imgs_translated)[2] // 2]
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(imgs_midpoint))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(10).minimize(loss)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Make test image
    xs, ys = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2, 1, 100), np.linspace(-1, 2, 75))
    test_img = (1 / (1 + np.square(xs))) * (1 / (1 + np.square(ys)))
    test_img /= np.max(test_img)
    test_img_batch = test_img[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis]
    # Train
    sess.run(init_op)
    for _ in range(100):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={imgs: test_img_batch})
    # Show result
    test_img_result = sess.run(imgs_translated, feed_dict={imgs: test_img_batch})[0, :, :, 0]
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.imshow(test_img)
    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.imshow(test_img_result)
```

Result:

[image: Test result]