# Arrange each pixel of a Tensor according to another Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Now, I am working on a work about registration using deep learning with the Keras backends. The state of task is that finish the registration between two images `fixed` and `moving`. Finally I get a deformation field `D(200,200,2)` where `200` is image size and `2` represents the offset of each pixel `dx, dy, dz`.I should apply `D` on `moving` and calculate loss with `fixed`.

The problem is that is there a way that I can arrange the pixels in `moving` according to `D` in Keras model?

Comment: That is tricky because, assuming you want to optimize the deformation field, that involves computing the gradient of the transformation by which an image is transformed, which I don't think is implemented in TensorFlow. I posted an answer in [this kind of related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52779070), although it's not the same case. I suppose in your case you have a batch of `fixed`, `moving` and deformation field values, right?

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you for your answer. The data I have is only `fixed` and `moving`. The deformation field can be calculated by FFD method, which can be implemented in CNN. The problem is that I can't arrange pixels in CNN just according the offset `D` of them, which indicates where pixels should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement the deformation using [`tf.contrib.resampler.resampler`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/resampler/resampler). It should just be something like `tf.contrib.resampler.resampler(moving, D)`, although you should note that it expects `moving` to be in the format `(batch_size, height, width, num_channels)` but then `D[..., 0]` is expected to contain width coordinates and `D[..., 1]` height coordinates. The operation implements gradients for both inputs, so it should work fine for training in any case.

If you don't want to use `tf.contrib` because [it is going to be removed from TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md), you may roll your own implementation of the bilinear interpolation. This is how it may look like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def deform(moving, deformation):
    # Performs bilinear interpolation
    s = tf.shape(moving)
    b, h, w = s[0], s[1], s[2]
    grid_b, grid_h, grid_w = tf.meshgrid(
        tf.range(b), tf.range(h), tf.range(w), indexing='ij')
    idx = tf.cast(tf.stack([grid_h, grid_w], axis=-1), deformation.dtype) + deformation
    idx_floor = tf.floor(idx)
    clip_low = tf.zeros([2], dtype=tf.int32)
    clip_high = tf.cast([h, w], dtype=tf.int32)
    # 0 0
    idx_00 = tf.clip_by_value(tf.cast(idx_floor, tf.int32), clip_low, clip_high)
    idx_batch = tf.expand_dims(grid_b, -1)
    idx_batch_00 = tf.concat([idx_batch, idx_00], axis=-1)
    moved_00 = tf.gather_nd(moving, idx_batch_00)
    # 0 1
    idx_01 = tf.clip_by_value(idx_00 + [0, 1], clip_low, clip_high)
    idx_batch_01 = tf.concat([idx_batch, idx_01], axis=-1)
    moved_01 = tf.gather_nd(moving, idx_batch_01)
    # 1 0
    idx_10 = tf.clip_by_value(idx_00 + [1, 0], clip_low, clip_high)
    idx_batch_10 = tf.concat([idx_batch, idx_10], axis=-1)
    moved_10 = tf.gather_nd(moving, idx_batch_10)
    # 1 1
    idx_11 = tf.clip_by_value(idx_00 + 1, clip_low, clip_high)
    idx_batch_11 = tf.concat([idx_batch, idx_11], axis=-1)
    moved_11 = tf.gather_nd(moving, idx_batch_11)
    # Interpolate
    alpha = idx - idx_floor
    alpha_h = alpha[..., 0]
    alpha_h_1 = 1 - alpha_h
    alpha_w = alpha[..., 1]
    alpha_w_1 = 1 - alpha_w
    moved_0 = moved_00 * alpha_w_1 + moved_01 * alpha_w
    moved_1 = moved_10 * alpha_w_1 + moved_11 * alpha_w
    moved = moved_0 * alpha_h_1 + moved_1 * alpha_h
    return moved
```

Interestingly, this shouldn't actually work, yet it probably does. The gradients will be estimated from the pixel values of the interpolated coordinates, meaning it will be more precise when deformation values are closer to a midpoint between two pixels than to the exact position of a pixel. However, for most images the difference is probably negligible.

If you want a more principled approach, you can use [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) to interpolate better pixel-wise gradient estimations:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def deform(moving, deformation):
    # Same code as before...
    # Gradient function
    def grad(dy):
        moving_pad = tf.pad(moving, [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], 'SYMMETRIC')
        # Diff H
        moving_dh_ref = moving_pad[:, 1:, 1:-1] - moving_pad[:, :-1, 1:-1]
        moving_dh_ref = (moving_dh_ref[:, :-1] + moving_dh_ref[:, 1:]) / 2
        moving_dh_0 = tf.gather_nd(moving_dh_ref, idx_batch_00)
        moving_dh_1 = tf.gather_nd(moving_dh_ref, idx_batch_10)
        moving_dh = moving_dh_1 * alpha_h_1 + moving_dh_1 * alpha_h
        # Diff W
        moving_dw_ref = moving_pad[:, 1:-1, 1:] - moving_pad[:, 1:-1, :-1]
        moving_dw_ref = (moving_dw_ref[:, :, :-1] + moving_dw_ref[:, :, 1:]) / 2
        moving_dw_0 = tf.gather_nd(moving_dw_ref, idx_batch_00)
        moving_dw_1 = tf.gather_nd(moving_dw_ref, idx_batch_01)
        moving_dw = moving_dw_1 * alpha_w_1 + moving_dw_1 * alpha_w
        # Gradient of deformation
        deformation_grad = tf.stack([tf.reduce_sum(dy * moving_dh, axis=-1),
                                     tf.reduce_sum(dy * moving_dw, axis=-1)], axis=-1)
        # Gradient of moving would be computed by applying the inverse deformation to dy
        # or just resorting to standard TensorFlow gradient, if needed
        return None, deformation_grad
    return moved, grad
```