# Tensorflow: How do I pass the gradient through an integer tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, backpropagation

I am having an issue maintaining the flow of gradients across a custom operation in my W-GAN network that I built with TensorFloww and Keras. I have structured the W-GAN to learn to produce an image "x" (let's assume that batch_size=1 for simplicity). That image is then passed to the function below that uses the learned images to index a filter bank look-up table (LUT). I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/ngan/main.py", line 141, in <module>
    gan.fit(training_images, batch_size=opts["BATCH_SIZE"], epochs=opts["EPOCHS"],
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 571, in train_function
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 951, in run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 2290, in call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 2649, in _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 282, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/ngan/ngan_test.py", line 352, in train_step
    self.generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 472, in apply_gradients
    grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/ngan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 1218, in _filter_grads
    raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv_layer_0/kernel:0', 'batch_normalization/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization/beta:0', 'conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'layer_normalization/gamma:0', 'layer_normalization/beta:0'].
```

Even through tf.gather_nd is a non-differentiable operation, the TensorFlow developers have seen fit to at least have it pass through the gradient, so I don't think that is the issue. I think the issue lies with the tf.cast to
integer operation. As far as I can tell TensorFlow has a gradient hard-stop across integer tensors. I even tried creating a tf.custom_gradient pass through like I did for the tf.round operation, but that also did not work. Can someone please suggest a way to index a LUT?

Code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def test_function(x, lut, xmin, xmax, filter_bank):
    """ 
    Parameters:
        x: learned image (float32); shape=(batch_size, width, height, 1)
        lut: look-up table (float32); shape=(1, 194, 12)
        xmin: left limit (float32); shape=(1,)
        xmax: right limit (float32); shape=(1,)
        flter_bank: a filter bank of functions (float32); shape=(width*heigh, 12)

    Returns:
        proc_image: processed image (float32); shape=(batch_size, width, height, 1)

    """

    @tf.custom_gradient
    def custom_round(x):
        """ Apply Floor operation and pass through gradient unchanged """
        def grad_fn(dy):
            return dy
        return tf.round(x), grad_fn

    # Convert incoming variable to a map of indices:
    index = (x - xmin) / xmax * lut.shape[1]
    index = K.cast(custom_round(index), dtype=tf.int32)
    index = layers.Flatten()(index)

    # Index the LUT:
    b = layers.Flatten()(K.cast(K.zeros_like(x), tf.int32))
    indices = K.stack([b, index], -1)
    indexed_weights = tf.gather_nd(lut, indices, batch_dims=0)

    # Calculated weighted sum of filter bank:
    proc_image = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(indexed_weights, filter_bank), axis=2, keepdims=True)

    return layers.Flatten()(proc_image)
```

I am running:

Version information:

```
tensorflow-gpu-v2.0.0
NVIDIA-SMI 430.64 / Driver Version: 430.64 / CUDA Version: 10.1
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
```

Comment: As you say, `gather_nd` is differentiable, but with respect to `params` only. I think you are trying to optimize what would be the `indices` in this case, for which there is no gradient, nor can be, since gradients do not exist for integer values. You'd need to replace that `gather_nd` operation with a differentiable equivalent, e.g. a bilinear interpolation or something. I posted something kind of like that, although in a different context, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55099884/1782792).

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment. if the matrix that I was interpolating varied smoothly between row indices, then that would absolutely work. However, for my case, the variable "lut" does not vary smoothly across its 194 rows. Each row holds a function that can be very different from its neighbors. I think I really do need an indexing operation here. Does it matter at all that there are no trainable parameters in this layer?

Comment: I don't think whether you have trainable parameters or not makes a difference in this case... The thing is, if your LUT is not smooth, then I'm not sure what would be the meaning of a gradient in that context... Note the gradient is supposed to represent "what happens to the output if I change this input by a small amount", but I'm not sure that is something meaningful in your problem. In general, gradient-based optimization assumes that all operations involved are differentiable, i.e. smooth. Otherwise, you cannot tell which way goes "down the slope".

Comment: Understood. This is what I suspected, but I am still very much still learning deep-learning optimization. Thank you for your explanation. Now, I need to figure out how to get the same effect without using a look-up table.

Comment: I tried implementing the method in your first reply. I am using tfa.image.resampler() from the tensorflow-addons library. However, I am getting the following error:

'ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: [_Derived_]No gradient defined for op: Addons>Resampler'

Comment: I suppose they didn't implement that gradient in the operation. They could, but I guess it may be a bit confusing, as the gradient would not be a smooth function (there would be "jumps" when you go from one pixel to the next), as in most cases with proper mathematical operations... I am honestly not quite sure why I thought the gradient in the first snippet was not fully correct (I'm also seeing that I could simplify those `tf.gather_nd` using `batch_dims=1`), but in any case, to do it with `tfa.image.resampler` you would need to compute the gradient by yourself with `tf.custom_gradient`.

Comment: For any analytical operation, calculating the gradient is as simple as taking the derivative with respect to its inputs. I am kind of at a loss for how to do this for an interpolation scheme, since the schema itself has an indexing operation. Can one even define a gradient for this kind of operation? Do you have any ideas on where to start for defining a gradient for the bilinear interpolation operation that is in tfa.image.resampler?

Comment: I have just tested the function `tfa.image.resampler` (TF 2.2.0, TFA 0.10.0) and I do get a gradient for both parameters of the function (like `data = ...; warp = ...; with tf.GradientTape() as tape: tape.watch(data); tape.watch(warp); res = tfa.image.resampler(data, warp); data_g, warp_g = tape.gradient(res, [data, warp])`, and both gradients are valid tensors).

Comment: Wooo! I tried tfa.image.reampler() again and now is works like a charm. The trick was to also migrate all of my code to TF2 conventions, so explicitly using the GradientTape and backpropagation operations. I am getting valid gradients and my model is converging to a reasonable solution. Thank you for all of your help!