# How to design Neural Network to behave like For-Loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, for-loop, neural-network

I want to move every pixel in an image by some value along the x-Axis.
The array "displacements" contains those displacement-values for each pixel:

Input:
image 240 x 320 x 3
array "displacements" 240 x 320

```py
    def apply_displacements(displacements, img):
        displacements = displacements * -100
        result_img = np.zeros(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3), dtype=float)

        for i in range(0, img_height):
            for j in range(0, img_width):
                disp = int(j + displacements[i][j])
                for k in range(0, 3):
                    if 0 <= disp <= (img_width-1):
                        result_img[i][disp][k] = img[0][i][j][k]
        return result_img
```

Output:
image with pixels from the original image but they were translated by the values
in the displacements-array

This function is necessary for a Neural Network that I'm working on, but a Loop is not differentiable.
I've read that you can create a Neural Network to imitate the behaviour of a function and the Network would therefore be differentiable. And that is what I am trying.

But what kind of NN-Model should I use? Are there some known Network-Architectures that would be efficient for tasks like these?
Convolutional NN because I'm working with images, but I'm not sure how many layers and what size the layers should have etc.
It would be supervised because I have the original function that should be simulated and the NN should
generate the same outputs as the original function.

I tried to google for it, but I'm not even sure what my search query should be. "Neural Network to simulate simple For-Loop"?

Any suggestions for the NN-Architecture?

Comment: In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52593481/1782792) I wrote an answer of how you can make a "differentiable translation". It's not the same as you're doing, though, since it's a single translation, not a displacement map, but it may be possible to adapt it to your problem...

Comment: I assume what you would want to optimize is the displacement map? Or is the displacement map fixed and you want to optimize the input image?

Comment: @jdehesa thanks I'll take a look at your link! Both the image and displacement map are fixed in this case and the net should train to apply the displacement map on the image correctly.

Comment: So you want to replace the displacement map algorithm for a neural network? That's different from what I had understood in the first place, if you wanted to do that you can just try out some convolutional architecture and see what happens. For simplicity, you could even just concatenate together the image with the displacement map as additional channels, then you would have a single input that you pass through multiple convolutional layers. But you'd have to experiment to see what works best. I'm not sure why you'd prefer a NN to the actual algorithm though.

Comment: @jdehesa What do you mean by the "actual algorithm"?

Comment: @jdehesa I added the original code and added some explanation, maybe its more understandable now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is actually what you want, or something you can use, but almost as a kind of exercise I put together a TensorFlow version of the algorithm you put there. I made it for arbitrary displacement maps along the vertical and horizontal coordinates, so your problem would be a subcase of it. It is slightly different to your algorithm, here if two pixels are moved to the same displaced coordinate their values are aggregated, instead of just taking the last one. Also, this algorithm uses bilinear interpolation to compute fractional displacements, which makes it differentiable.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def image_displace_tf(img, disp):
    # Get image shape
    s = tf.shape(img, out_type=tf.int64)
    # Image shape as floats
    sf = tf.dtypes.cast(s, disp.dtype)
    # Make coordinate grid
    bb, ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(s[0]), tf.range(s[1]), tf.range(s[2]),
                             indexing='ij')
    # Compute displaced coordinates
    coords = tf.stack([bb, ii, jj], axis=-1)
    # Add a null "batch displacement"
    disp_pad = tf.pad(disp, [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0]])
    coords_disp = tf.dtypes.cast(coords, disp.dtype) + disp_pad
    # Mask displacements out of range
    mask = ((coords_disp[..., 1] >= 0) & (coords_disp[..., 1] < sf[1] - 1) &
            (coords_disp[..., 2] >= 0) & (coords_disp[..., 2] < sf[2] - 1))
    coords = tf.boolean_mask(coords, mask)
    coords_disp = tf.boolean_mask(coords_disp, mask)
    # Compute interpolation alpha values for bilinear interpolation
    alpha_1 = tf.math.floormod(coords_disp, 1.0)
    alpha_1 = tf.expand_dims(alpha_1, axis=-1)
    alpha_0 = 1 - alpha_1
    alpha_00 = alpha_0[..., 1, :] * alpha_0[..., 2, :]
    alpha_01 = alpha_0[..., 1, :] * alpha_1[..., 2, :]
    alpha_10 = alpha_1[..., 1, :] * alpha_0[..., 2, :]
    alpha_11 = alpha_1[..., 1, :] * alpha_1[..., 2, :]
    # Begin and end indices for each dimension
    idx_00 = tf.dtypes.cast(coords_disp, tf.int64)
    idx_01 = idx_00 + [0, 0, 1]
    idx_10 = idx_00 + [0, 1, 0]
    idx_11 = idx_00 + [0, 1, 1]
    # Values at begin and end for each dimension scaled by their alpha values
    img_coords = tf.gather_nd(img, coords)
    value_00 = alpha_00 * img_coords
    value_01 = alpha_01 * img_coords
    value_10 = alpha_10 * img_coords
    value_11 = alpha_11 * img_coords
    # Concatenate all indices and values
    idx_all = tf.concat([idx_00, idx_01, idx_10, idx_11], axis=0)
    value_all = tf.concat([value_00, value_01, value_10, value_11], axis=0)
    # Make aggregated result
    return tf.scatter_nd(idx_all, value_all, s)
```

I'm not sure if it will work as you hope, but you can take gradients of both the image and the displacement map. This is how you could use it:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf.random.set_seed(0)
plt.close('all')
# Make a radial image
x = tf.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 400)
y = tf.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 300)
r = tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.square(x) + tf.math.square(tf.expand_dims(y, 1)))
img = tf.math.maximum(0.8 - r, 0.0)
# Give it three channels
img = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(img, axis=-1), [1, 1, 3])
# Add batch dimension
img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
# Show image
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img.numpy()[0])
plt.title('Source image')
plt.show()

# Make a wavy displacement map along the horizontal axis
s = tf.shape(img)
disp_i = tf.zeros(s[:-1], dtype=img.dtype)
_, ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(*(tf.linspace(0.0, 1.0, si) for si in s[:3]), indexing='ij')
disp_j = 5.0 * (tf.sin(40.0 * jj + tf.sin(20.0 * ii)))
disp = tf.stack([disp_i, disp_j], axis=-1)
# Show map
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(0.5 + 0.5 * disp.numpy()[0, ..., 1])
plt.title('Horizontal displacement map')
plt.show()

# Do displacement
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(img)
    g.watch(disp)
    img_disp = image_displace_tf(img, disp)
    # Some minimization goal - e.g. sum of squared pixel values
    goal = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.square(img_disp))
# Show result
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img_disp.numpy()[0])
plt.title('Displaced image')
plt.show()
# Show gradients
img_grad, disp_grad = g.gradient(goal, [img, disp])
# Gradient of image
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img_grad.numpy()[0, ..., 0])
plt.title('Image gradient')
plt.show()
# Gradient of horizontal coorindate of displacement map
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(disp_grad.numpy()[0, ..., 1])
plt.title('Horizontal displacement gradient')
plt.show()
```

Output images:

[image: Source image]
[image: Horizontal displacement map]
[image: Displaced image]
[image: Image gradient]
[image: Horizontal displacement gradient]

Comment: ...WOW. I'm not quite sure yet how your code works, but the results look impressive. I'll try your code in the evening and will respond then!

Comment: @user3019423 The idea is not so complicated, if the pixel `p` at `i, j` is displaced by `di, dj` (which are float values, not integer), you take the value of `p` and distribute it between the four points `floor(i+di), floor(i+dj)`, `floor(i+di), ceil(i+dj)`, `ceil(i+di), floor(i+dj)` and `ceil(i+di), ceil(i+dj)`, according to the fractional part of `di` and `dj` (the `alpha` values). However, the code gets a bit complicated, so it's entirely possible I made a mistake, or I'm not doing exactly what you wanted. Do as much checking as you can and comment if something is wrong.

Comment: It says:  
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 2 for 'add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [1,240,320,3], [1,240,320,2].  

its happening in following line:
coords_disp = tf.dtypes.cast(coords, disp.dtype) + disp_pad


I tried to find out where the dimensions are set, but I couldnt find it yet

Comment: @user3019423 Does the example I put work for you? Note the function `image_displace_tf` assumes that the input `img` has shape `[batch_size, height, width, num_channels]`, and `disp` has shape `[batch_size, height, width, 2]` (for each pixel there is a vertical and horizontal displacement value).